# Smart Screen bloqueia minha aplicação

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, clickonce

Ao publicar um aplicação com Visual Studio usando o ClickOnce 
No Windows 7, ao instalar ou atualizar, é exibido o Aviso de Segurança abaixo o que não vem a ser um problema, mas incomoda.

[image: MENSAGEM WINDOWS 7]

Já no Windows 8.0 (e nas versões posteriores, acredito) está me gerando problemas. Na figura abaixo, cliquei em mostrar mais detalhes. Além do do aplicativo não ser reconhecido, também não fornece o nome do fornecedor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como faço para cadastrar meu **aplicativo** e **nome de fornecedor** na Microsoft, de forma a tornar meu software confiável e evitar essas mensagens no SmartScreen?

Comment: Amigo, sua dúvida foi respondida em: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application Espero ter ajudado.